# "Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error" when sending http post request in Angular in browser and android

Tags: angular, http, ionic-framework, camera, capacitor

this is my code

```typescript
takeFirstPicture = async () => {
  const convertBlobToBase64 = (blob: Blob) =>   new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onerror = reject;
  reader.onload = () => {
    resolve(reader.result);
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(blob);   });

  const image = await Camera.getPhoto({
    quality: 90,
    allowEditing: false,
    resultType: CameraResultType.Uri
  });
  var imageUrl = image.webPath;  
  this.signaturePhoto1 = imageUrl;

  const response = await fetch(image.webPath!);
  this.blob_photo1 = await response.blob();
  this.base64Data_photo1 = (await convertBlobToBase64(this.blob_photo1));   
};

takeSecondPicture = async () => {
  const convertBlobToBase64 = (blob: Blob) =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onerror = reject;
    reader.onload = () => {
      resolve(reader.result);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
  });

  const image = await Camera.getPhoto({
    quality: 90,
    allowEditing: false,
    resultType: CameraResultType.Uri
  });
  var imageUrl = image.webPath;  
  this.signaturePhoto2 = imageUrl;

  const response = await fetch(image.webPath!);
  this.blob_photo2 = await response.blob();
  this.base64Data_photo2 = (await convertBlobToBase64(this.blob_photo2));   };

async sendPostRequest() {
  this.distance_value.result ='';

  this.loadingController.create({
    message: 'Loading...'
  }).then((response) => {
    response.present();
  });

  var httpHeader = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT'})
  };
  let files = {
          file1: this.base64Data_photo1,
          file2: this.base64Data_photo2
  }
  const jsonString = JSON.stringify(files);
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('files', this.base64Data_photo1);

  this.http.post("https://API_URL/", files, httpHeader)
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.distance_value = data;
      console.log("************************", data);
      this.loadingController.dismiss().then((response) => {
        console.log('Loader closed!', response);
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.log('Error occured : ', err);
      });
      }, error => {
      console.log("ERROR ====>>",error);
      this.distance_value.result = "Error!"
      this.loadingController.dismiss().then((response) => {
        console.log('Loader closed!', response);
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.log('Error occured : ', err);
      });
    });

} }
```

here's the response from server in both browser and android!

```
message: Http failure response for https://API_URL/: 0 Unknown Error"
```

I searched a lot without success. Any Help please!

Answer (score 0):

If `API_URL` is a variable, then you are not providing it correctly. Try this:

```typescript
this.http.post(`https://${API_URL}/`, files, httpHeader)
```

If it just a placeholder you copied from somewhere, then you also have to declare and initialize it. The common use case is that you hold a BASE PATH in such variable and then combine it with the path of an endpoint you are trying to reach.

```
// if you have different environments (dev, test, prod, etc.), use env file
private readonly BASE_PATH = environment.basePath
// or just write it down
private readonly BASE_PATH = 'https://API_ADDRESS:PORT/path'

//and then you can use it like this
this.http.post(`${BASE_PATH }/myEndpoint/`, files, httpHeader)
```

Comment: thanks for responding, but i type the URL directly, it's not a variable.